# make "collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

Tags: makefile, fortran, linker-errors

Before the start,I'm a newbie in linux, and I try to compile THE "MESOSCALE MODEL INTERFACE PROGRAM (MMIF)" but I stuck.Anyway,the model has a compiler "makefile". I edited my "makefile" my own lib and location but I'm receive this error code,"collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status". What is this solution, how can i solve this?

**ERROR CODE**

```
gfortran -g -Wall -O2 -I/usr/include -lm -fbounds-check           -static                  -I/netcdf/include -c output_aercoare.f90 -o output_aercoare.o
gfortran -g -Wall -O2 -I/usr/include -lm -fbounds-check           -static                  -I/netcdf/include -c output_aermet.f90 -o output_aermet.o
gfortran -g -Wall -O2 -I/usr/include -lm -fbounds-check           -static                  -I/netcdf/include -c output_calmet.f90 -o output_calmet.o
gfortran -g -Wall -O2 -I/usr/include -lm -fbounds-check           -static                  -I/netcdf/include -c output_onsite.f90 -o output_onsite.o
gfortran -g -Wall -O2 -I/usr/include -lm -fbounds-check           -static                  -I/netcdf/include -c output_scichem.f90 -o output_scichem.o
output_scichem.f90:379.39:

     write(iUnit) (NAMDUM,   i=1,NREPER),       &    ! rec 9 names, units
                                       1
Warning: DO loop at (1) will be executed zero times
output_scichem.f90:418.44:

     write(iUnit,9001) (NAMDUM,   i=1,NREPER), &     ! rec 9 names and units
                                            1
Warning: DO loop at (1) will be executed zero times
gfortran -g -Wall -O2 -I/usr/include -lm -fbounds-check           -static                  -I/netcdf/include -c pasquill_gifford.f90 -o pasquill_gifford.o
gfortran -g -Wall -O2 -I/usr/include -lm -fbounds-check           -static                  -I/netcdf/include -c pbl_height.f90 -o pbl_height.o
pbl_height.f90: In function ‘pbl_height’:
pbl_height.f90:110:0: warning: ‘zl’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   pbl = zl
 ^
pbl_height.f90:105:0: warning: ‘thetaold’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
      ThetaL = ThetaOld + frac*(Theta   - ThetaOld)
 ^
pbl_height.f90:55:0: warning: ‘theta’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   real theta,theta2                  ! potential temperature
 ^
gfortran -g -Wall -O2 -I/usr/include -lm -fbounds-check           -static                  -I/netcdf/include -c read_mm5.f90 -o read_mm5.o
gfortran -g -Wall -O2 -I/usr/include -lm -fbounds-check           -static                  -I/netcdf/include -c read_wrf.f90 -o read_wrf.o
gfortran -g -Wall -O2 -I/usr/include -lm -fbounds-check           -static                  -I/netcdf/include -c sfc_layer.f90 -o sfc_layer.o
gfortran -g -Wall -O2 -I/usr/include -lm -fbounds-check           -static                  -I/netcdf/include -c timesubs.f90 -o timesubs.o
gfortran -g -Wall -O2 -I/usr/include -lm -fbounds-check           -static                  met_fields.o functions.o module_llxy.o wrf_netcdf.o parse_control.o aggregate.o avg_zface.o cloud_cover.o interpolate.o landuse.o mmif.o output_aercoare.o output_aermet.o output_calmet.o output_onsite.o output_scichem.o pasquill_gifford.o pbl_height.o read_mm5.o read_wrf.o sfc_layer.o timesubs.o -L/netcdf/lib -lnetcdf -lnetcdff -lm -lm -o mmif
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-attio.o): In function `nf_put_att_text_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-attio.c:14: undefined reference to `nc_put_att_text'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-attio.o): In function `nf_get_att_text_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-attio.c:21: undefined reference to `nc_get_att_text'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-attio.o): In function `nf_put_att_int1_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-attio.c:29: undefined reference to `nc_put_att_schar'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-attio.o): In function `nf_get_att_int1_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-attio.c:47: undefined reference to `nc_get_att_schar'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-attio.o): In function `nf_put_att_int2_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-attio.c:65: undefined reference to `nc_put_att_short'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-attio.o): In function `nf_get_att_int2_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-attio.c:80: undefined reference to `nc_get_att_short'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-attio.o): In function `nf_put_att_int_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-attio.c:95: undefined reference to `nc_put_att_int'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-attio.o): In function `nf_get_att_int_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-attio.c:107: undefined reference to `nc_get_att_int'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-attio.o): In function `nf_put_att_real_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-attio.c:122: undefined reference to `nc_put_att_float'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-attio.o): In function `nf_get_att_real_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-attio.c:134: undefined reference to `nc_get_att_float'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-attio.o): In function `nf_put_att_double_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-attio.c:142: undefined reference to `nc_put_att_double'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-attio.o): In function `nf_get_att_double_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-attio.c:149: undefined reference to `nc_get_att_double'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-attio.o): In function `nf_put_att_text_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-attio.c:14: undefined reference to `nc_put_att_text'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-attio.o): In function `nf_get_att_text_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-attio.c:21: undefined reference to `nc_get_att_text'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-attio.o): In function `nf_put_att_int1_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-attio.c:29: undefined reference to `nc_put_att_schar'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-attio.o): In function `nf_get_att_int1_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-attio.c:47: undefined reference to `nc_get_att_schar'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-attio.o): In function `nf_put_att_int2_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-attio.c:65: undefined reference to `nc_put_att_short'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-attio.o): In function `nf_get_att_int2_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-attio.c:80: undefined reference to `nc_get_att_short'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-attio.o): In function `nf_put_att_int_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-attio.c:95: undefined reference to `nc_put_att_int'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-attio.o): In function `nf_get_att_int_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-attio.c:107: undefined reference to `nc_get_att_int'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-attio.o): In function `nf_put_att_real_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-attio.c:122: undefined reference to `nc_put_att_float'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-attio.o): In function `nf_get_att_real_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-attio.c:134: undefined reference to `nc_get_att_float'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-attio.o): In function `nf_put_att_double_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-attio.c:142: undefined reference to `nc_put_att_double'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-attio.o): In function `nf_get_att_double_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-attio.c:149: undefined reference to `nc_get_att_double'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-control.o): In function `nf_create_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-control.c:13: undefined reference to `nc_create'
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-control.c:13: undefined reference to `nc_create'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-control.o): In function `nf__create_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-control.c:20: undefined reference to `nc__create'
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-control.c:20: undefined reference to `nc__create'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-control.o): In function `nf_open_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-control.c:27: undefined reference to `nc_open'
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-control.c:27: undefined reference to `nc_open'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-control.o): In function `nf__open_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-control.c:34: undefined reference to `nc__open'
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-control.c:34: undefined reference to `nc__open'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-control.o): In function `nf_set_fill_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-control.c:41: undefined reference to `nc_set_fill'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-control.o): In function `nf_set_default_format_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-control.c:48: undefined reference to `nc_set_default_format'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-control.o): In function `nf_delete_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-control.c:99: undefined reference to `nc_delete'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-control.o): In function `nf__create_mp_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-control.c:105: undefined reference to `nc__create_mp'
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-control.c:105: undefined reference to `nc__create_mp'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-control.o): In function `nf__open_mp_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-control.c:111: undefined reference to `nc__open_mp'
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-control.c:111: undefined reference to `nc__open_mp'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-control.o): In function `nf_delete_mp_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-control.c:117: undefined reference to `nc_delete_mp'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-control.o): In function `nf_inq_base_pe_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-control.c:129: undefined reference to `nc_inq_base_pe'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-control.o): In function `nf_redef_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-control.c:55: undefined reference to `nc_redef'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-control.o): In function `nf_enddef_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-control.c:62: undefined reference to `nc_enddef'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-control.o): In function `nf__enddef_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-control.c:69: undefined reference to `nc__enddef'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-control.o): In function `nf_sync_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-control.c:77: undefined reference to `nc_sync'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-control.o): In function `nf_abort_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-control.c:84: undefined reference to `nc_abort'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-control.o): In function `nf_close_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-control.c:91: undefined reference to `nc_close'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-control.o): In function `nf_delete_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-control.c:99: undefined reference to `nc_delete'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-control.o): In function `nf_delete_mp_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-control.c:117: undefined reference to `nc_delete_mp'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-control.o): In function `nf_set_base_pe_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-control.c:123: undefined reference to `nc_set_base_pe'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-dim.o): In function `nf_def_dim_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-dim.c:20: undefined reference to `nc_def_dim'
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-dim.c:20: undefined reference to `nc_def_dim'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-dim.o): In function `nf_inq_dimid_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-dim.c:27: undefined reference to `nc_inq_dimid'
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-dim.c:27: undefined reference to `nc_inq_dimid'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-dim.o): In function `nf_inq_dim_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-dim.c:34: undefined reference to `nc_inq_dim'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-dim.o): In function `nf_inq_dimname_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-dim.c:41: undefined reference to `nc_inq_dimname'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-dim.o): In function `nf_inq_dimlen_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-dim.c:48: undefined reference to `nc_inq_dimlen'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-dim.o): In function `nf_rename_dim_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-dim.c:55: undefined reference to `nc_rename_dim'
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-dim.c:55: undefined reference to `nc_rename_dim'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-genvar.o): In function `nf_def_var_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-genvar.c:20: undefined reference to `nc_def_var'
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-genvar.c:20: undefined reference to `nc_def_var'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-genvar.o): In function `nf_inq_var_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-genvar.c:27: undefined reference to `nc_inq_var'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-genvar.o): In function `nf_inq_varid_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-genvar.c:34: undefined reference to `nc_inq_varid'
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-genvar.c:34: undefined reference to `nc_inq_varid'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-genvar.o): In function `nf_inq_varname_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-genvar.c:41: undefined reference to `nc_inq_varname'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-genvar.o): In function `nf_inq_vartype_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-genvar.c:48: undefined reference to `nc_inq_vartype'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-genvar.o): In function `nf_inq_varndims_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-genvar.c:55: undefined reference to `nc_inq_varndims'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-genvar.o): In function `nf_inq_vardimid_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-genvar.c:62: undefined reference to `nc_inq_vardimid'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-genvar.o): In function `nf_inq_varnatts_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-genvar.c:69: undefined reference to `nc_inq_varnatts'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-genvar.o): In function `nf_rename_var_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-genvar.c:76: undefined reference to `nc_rename_var'
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-genvar.c:76: undefined reference to `nc_rename_var'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-genvar.o): In function `nf_copy_var_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-genvar.c:83: undefined reference to `nc_copy_var'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-lib.o): In function `c2f_dimids':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-lib.c:27: undefined reference to `nc_inq_varndims'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-lib.o): In function `c2f_chunksizes':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-lib.c:57: undefined reference to `nc_inq_varndims'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-lib.o): In function `f2c_chunksizes':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-lib.c:73: undefined reference to `nc_inq_varndims'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-lib.o): In function `f2c_coords':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-lib.c:92: undefined reference to `nc_inq_varndims'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-lib.o): In function `f2c_counts':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-lib.c:112: undefined reference to `nc_inq_varndims'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-lib.o):/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-lib.c:134: more undefined references to `nc_inq_varndims' follow
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-lib.o): In function `nc_inq_varids_f':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-lib.c:165: undefined reference to `nc_inq_varids'
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-lib.c:169: undefined reference to `nc_inq_varids'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-lib.o): In function `nc_inq_dimids_f':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-lib.c:194: undefined reference to `nc_inq_dimids'
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-lib.c:198: undefined reference to `nc_inq_dimids'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-lib.o): In function `nc_insert_array_compound_f':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-lib.c:235: undefined reference to `nc_insert_array_compound'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-lib.o): In function `nc_inq_compound_field_f':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-lib.c:252: undefined reference to `nc_inq_compound_field'
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-lib.c:257: undefined reference to `nc_inq_compound_field'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-varaio.o): In function `nf_put_vara_text_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-varaio.c:22: undefined reference to `nc_put_vara_text'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-varaio.o): In function `nf_get_vara_text_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-varaio.c:29: undefined reference to `nc_get_vara_text'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-varaio.o): In function `nf_put_vara_int1_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-varaio.c:37: undefined reference to `nc_put_vara_schar'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-varaio.o): In function `nf_get_vara_int1_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-varaio.c:55: undefined reference to `nc_get_vara_schar'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-varaio.o): In function `nf_put_vara_int2_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-varaio.c:73: undefined reference to `nc_put_vara_short'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-varaio.o): In function `nf_get_vara_int2_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-varaio.c:88: undefined reference to `nc_get_vara_short'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-varaio.o): In function `nf_put_vara_int_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-varaio.c:103: undefined reference to `nc_put_vara_int'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-varaio.o): In function `nf_get_vara_int_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-varaio.c:115: undefined reference to `nc_get_vara_int'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-varaio.o): In function `nf_put_vara_real_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-varaio.c:130: undefined reference to `nc_put_vara_float'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-varaio.o): In function `nf_get_vara_real_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-varaio.c:142: undefined reference to `nc_get_vara_float'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-varaio.o): In function `nf_put_vara_double_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-varaio.c:150: undefined reference to `nc_put_vara_double'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-varaio.o): In function `nf_get_vara_double_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-varaio.c:157: undefined reference to `nc_get_vara_double'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-varaio.o): In function `nf_put_vara_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-varaio.c:160: undefined reference to `nc_put_vara'
/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.a(fort-varaio.o): In function `nf_get_vara_':
/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-fortran-4.2/fortran/fort-varaio.c:163: undefined reference to `nc_get_vara'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [mmif] Error 1
```

---

System = Virtualbox6.1>>ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-amd64

İnstallation =
-MPICH-3.2.1
-zlib-1.2.1
-jasper-1.900.1
-libpng-1.6.34
-hdf5-1.8.20
-netcdf-4.1.3
-netcdf-fortran-4.2

```
    This netCDF 4.1.3 has been built with the following features: 
    
      --cc        -> gcc
      --cflags    ->  -I/usr/include -DgFortran
      --libs      -> -L/usr/lib -lnetcdf
    
      --cxx       -> g++
      --has-c++   -> yes
    
      --fc        -> gfortran
      --fflags    -> -g -O2 -I/usr/include
      --flibs     -> -L/usr/lib -lnetcdff -lnetcdf
      --has-f77   -> yes
      --has-f90   -> yes
    
      --has-dap   -> yes
      --has-nc2   -> yes
      --has-nc4   -> yes
      --has-hdf5  -> yes
      --has-hdf4  -> no
      --has-pnetcdf-> no
      --has-szlib -> 
    
      --prefix    -> /usr
      --includedir-> /usr/include
      --version   -> netCDF 4.1.3
```

**~/.bashrc**

```
export fld_install=/home/asdfg585/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES
export CC=gcc
export CXX=g++
export FC=gfortran
export FCFLAGS=-m64
export F77=gfortran
export FFLAGS=-m64
export PATH=fld_install/mpich/bin:$PATH
export JASPERLIB=$fld_install/grib2/lib
export JASPERINC=$fld_install/grib2/include
export PATH="$fld_install/hdf5/bin:$PATH $fld_install/netcdf/bin:$PATH "
export HDF5=$fld_install/hdf5
export LDFLAGS="-L$fld_install/grib2/lib -L$fld_install/hdf5/lib -L$fld_install/netcdf/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I$fld_install/grib2/include -I$fld_install/hdf5/include -I$fld_install/netcdf/include"
export NETCDF=$fld_install/netcdf
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$fld_install/netcdf/lib
```

**makefile**

```
#
# Makefile for MMIF VERSION 3.4.1 2019-03-11
#
# Edit this file to un-comment the section for your compiler.  
# You will also need to edit the line that specifies where to find the 
# NetCDF libraries, which must be compiled by the same compiler.
# The directory "netcdf.4.1.1-mingw" is used to commpile under MS Windows.
# It was compiled using MinGW version 20110802, see http://www.mingw.org, 
# and the script compile_netcdf_mingw.sh.
#
# PGI started linking with the OpenMP library by default in their 11.0 release,
# so that users would be able to use CPU binding even with serial code.  
# Adding "-mp=nonuma -nomp" to FFLAGS fixes "can't find libnuma.so" problems.

# PGI Fortran:
#FC = pgf90
#FFLAGS = -g -fast -Mlfs           # -Mlfs is default on for x86_64
# FFLAGS += -Mbounds              # for bounds checking/debugging
#FFLAGS += -Bstatic_pgi            # to use static PGI libraries
#FFLAGS += -Bstatic                # to use static netCDF libraries
#FFLAGS += -mp=nonuma -nomp        # fix for "can't find libnuma.so"
#NETCDF = /usr/local/src/netcdf-4.1.1.pgi

# GNU gfortran (Windows or Linux, just set NETCDF below correctly)
FC = gfortran
FFLAGS = -g -Wall
FFLAGS += -fbounds-check          # for bounds checking/debugging
FFLAGS += -static                 # to use static libraries
NETCDF = /netcdf

# Intel Fortran:
#FC = ifort
#FFLAGS = -O2 -align dcommons -ipo
#FFLAGS += -static                 # to use static libraries
#NETCDF = /path/to/netcdf-4.1.1.ifort

# NETCDF values that are the same for all compilers
INCL = -I$(NETCDF)/include
LIBS = -L$(NETCDF)/lib -lnetcdf -lnetcdff

PROGRAM = mmif

TODAY   = 2019-03-11
VERSION = 3.4.1
NEWTAG  = 3.4.1 2019-03-11
OLDTAG  = 3.4.1 2019-03-01

MODULES = met_fields.f90 functions.f90 module_llxy.f90 wrf_netcdf.f90     \
    parse_control.f90

SOURCES = aggregate.f90 avg_zface.f90 cloud_cover.f90 interpolate.f90     \
    landuse.f90 mmif.f90 output_aercoare.f90 output_aermet.f90        \
    output_calmet.f90 output_onsite.f90 output_scichem.f90            \
    pasquill_gifford.f90 pbl_height.f90 read_mm5.f90 read_wrf.f90     \
    sfc_layer.f90 timesubs.f90 

OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.f90=.o)
MODOBJS = $(MODULES:.f90=.o)
MODMODS = $(MODULES:.f90=.mod)

$(PROGRAM): $(MODOBJS) $(OBJECTS)
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(MODOBJS) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS) -o $@

%.o : %.f90 
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(INCL) -c $< -o $@

install: $(PROGRAM)
    cp $(PROGRAM) /usr/local/bin
        #cp $(PROGRAM) /usr/local/bin /home/asdfg585/MMIFv3.4.1_2019-03-11
update_version: 
    sed -i "s|VERSION $(OLDTAG)|VERSION $(NEWTAG)|g" \
        *.f90 README.txt makefile makefile.windows mmif_change_log.txt

distro: 
    mmif --sample > mmif.inp
    unix2dos *.f90 *.sh makefile.windows old_compile.bat README*.txt mmif.inp
    zip -j MMIFv$(VERSION)_$(TODAY).zip \
        mmif.exe mmif mmif.inp *.f90 *.sh makefile \
        makefile.windows old_compile.bat README*.txt \
        MMIFv$(VERSION)_Users_Manual.pdf \
        mmif_change_log.txt test_problems/*/*.inp
    dos2unix *.f90

test_pkg: 
    zip -r MMIFv$(VERSION)_test_problems.zip \
        test_problems -x \*/wrf/\* \*/mm5/\*

test_pkg_mm5+wrf:
    zip -r MMIF_test_problems_mm5+wrf.zip \
        test_problems/wrf \
        test_problems/mm5

clean:
    rm $(MODMODS) $(MODOBJS) $(OBJECTS) $(PROGRAM)
```

**what I have tried before.**

changing -lnetcdf to -lnetcdff

different systems like "fedora,mint,ubuntu14/18/20".Also include windows "Mys2,mingw,cygwin"

more recent versions like "netcdf-4.7.1,g++ 9.2.0"

---

Thank you from now.

Comment: What if you use `-lnetcdff -lnetcdf` instead of `-lnetcdf -lnetcdff` (as suggested by the configuration data)?

Comment: Is this useful:https://askubuntu.com/questions/445881/collect2-error-while-compiling-fortran-code